# How to hide or give attributes to the button based on time odoo12?

Tags: odoo

I have a date time field in the form view,and in the form view i need to hide the button based on the time.(Like an hour before the time in the date time field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to do so.

In you respective model add **`compute`** Boolean field.

**For Example:**

```
class InheritSaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    show_hide_button = fields.Boolean(compute='_get_visible')
    
    def _get_visible(self):
        //Here you can write your code
        if YOUR_LOGIC:
           self.show_hide_button = True
        else:
           self.show_hide_button = False
```

**In XML:**

```
<field name="show_hide_button" invisible="1"/>
<button name="your_button" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('show_hide_button', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Second you can use **`@api.onchange`** to make it hide and visible according to time.

Comment: thanks for the response,i appreciate.so can i write my logic corresponding to the field(time) like before an hour of the field(time) i can show the button?

Comment: @Raihan yes you can

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge bro.

Comment: If you find solution then please mark this as an answer for others and to motivate me.